# How to save .class file in different directory in java

Tags: java

When we create and compile a .java file .class file created on same folder. How to save .class files in different folder and run it?

Comment: do you ever heard about **packages**????

Comment: how are you creating the .class files?

Comment: I would not suggest such a thing. It could break your package structure.

Comment: Consider using some kind of build tool, like Ant or Maven for example

Comment: please provide more information what are you using when you create .class files? What IDE? Eclipse, Netbeans, IDEA etc? Are you using packages in your project?

Comment: You might be interested in learning about Maven, Gradle, and/or a decent IDE, like IntelliJ Idea or NetBeans.

Comment: You could also use the `-d` parameter to `javac`, *"-d <directory>             Specify where to place generated class files"*

Comment: Have you considered reading the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)?

Comment: Hi Ankit, No I have not heard about that. But my scenario is that, I create a HelloWorld.java file and compile it. After that HelloWorld.class file created on same folder. Is it possible to save .class file differently  and run from cmd?

Comment: @TufanBanerjee - yes you could do it.. If you have just one class, you could place it anywhere and run it.

Comment: @TufanBanerjee I thing MadProgrammer gave the soln in his 2nd comment...Go for it..

Comment: @TheLostMind how will I do it?

Comment: @TufanBanerjee *how will I do it*....!!!!!! God may help you...

Comment: @AnkitLamba I create it successfully. Thanks to all of you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

javac -d workspace/projectdir file.java

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse, Right click your project > Properties > Java Build Path > Source Tab > `Default Output Folder`.

Class files are stored here, change this folder path.

Comment: Hi @java Learner. I have just try it with notepad and cmd.